# Where can I define and set dokku nginx log format globally, for all apps?

Tags: nginx, dokku

I need to set up a specific log format for all my apps, but I only get errors when trying to set a http header at /var/lib/dokku/plugins/available/nginx-vhosts/templates/nginx.conf.template :

```
http {
    log_format log_with_timing '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
    '$request_time $upstream_response_time';

    server {
      listen      [::]:$NGINX_PORT;
      listen      $NGINX_PORT;
      server_name $NOSSL_SERVER_NAME;
      access_log  /var/log/nginx/${APP}-access.log log_with_timing;
      error_log   /var/log/nginx/${APP}-error.log log_with_timing;

      location    / {
       # ...
      }
}
```

Where can I set the http header at the dokku templates? I cannot find it.

If this cannot be done, how could this be done on a per application basis?

Dokku version: 0.4.3

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Dokku that do not use Sigil, you need to escape the `$`, otherwise it will be interpolated in bash.

I highly recommend upgrading to the latest version of dokku, which avoids this issue completely by using sigil for file templating.

Comment: Thank you Jose. Now we had to lay aside of this, but when we come back we'll try with a newer Dokku version.